# Docky not showing up in the task manager?

Tags: docky, kill, task-management

Docky is frozen, but I can't find it in the task manager. How do I kill it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you can start Docky with the command `docky`, when the application is running (whether with this command or auto-started on boot) it is later found in the task manager under the following name:

```
mono /usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe
```

Alternatively, you can also kill it from the terminal (this command should continue to work even if Docky switches from using Mono to using standard Linux binaries):

```
kill $(pgrep docky)
```